# How to set an Angular2/4 Class Variable via html

Tags: html, angular, variables, directive

I am trying to set an Angular2 Class Variable via html.
This is what I've Tried
The problem is that although the value gets set via

```
<div class="row" *ngVar="client.clientName as clientName">
```

It doesn't keep the value on the loop. It's only seems to have a value after the declaration.

**Directive**

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngVar]',
})
export class VarDirective {
    @Input()
    set ngVar(context: any) {
        this.context.$implicit = this.context.ngVar = context;
        this.updateView();
    }

    context: any = {};

    constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}

    updateView() {
        this.vcRef.clear();
        this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context);
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'details', 
    template: `      
                <div class="row" *ngVar="'' as clientName">                        
                <ng-template *ngIf="clients.length" ngFor [ngForOf]="clients" let-client>
                aaaaaaaaa|{{clientName}}|aaaaaaaa                   
                    <div class="row" *ngIf="clientName != client.clientName">
                        <div>                               
                            <div class="row" *ngVar="client.clientName as clientName">
                                bbbbbbbb|{{clientName}}|bbbbbbbbb                           
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </ng-template> 
               </div>        
    `    
})
export class ComponentName {
    className: string = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the way I achieved this was

1. Removing the directive.
2. Creating a class function to set the variable

   ```
   setVariable(clientName) {
       this.clientName = clientName;
   }
   ```
3. Then in the loop I added the function in an interpolation tag

   ```
   <ng-template *ngIf="clients.length" ngFor [ngForOf]="clients" let-client>
       aaaaaaaaa|{{clientName}}|aaaaaaaa                   
       <div class="row" *ngIf="clientName != client.clientName">Hey
           <div>
               {{setVariable(statesWithClient.client.clientName)}}
               bbbbbbbb|{{clientName}}|bbbbbbbbb                           
           </div>  
       </div>
   </ng-template>
   ```

The issue I am having now is getting an error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'

**The Hack**

Reading this [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15464) I ran across "when changing a component 'non model' value" - simple enough I'll just add the ngmodel.

```
<input type="hidden" ngModel #clientName />
```

**It Works. no more error**

**But Now**

But now error code no longer detects clientName != statesWithClient.client.clientName.